# Apache httpd configuration: sysconfig/apache2 and apache2/httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm new to Apache and Linux, and I'm reading through `httpd.conf`. I've come to a line in `default-server.conf` where it says:

> # UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
>   # directory if a ~user request is received.
>   #
>   # To disable it, simply remove userdir from the list of modules in APACHE_MODULES
>   # in /etc/sysconfig/apache2.
>   #

What's the relation between that file and the `httpd.conf` file (and the others possibly included by that) inside `/etc/apache2/`? I'm more concerned about modules, but a general explanation would help.

Answer (score 0):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html

Apache HTTP Server is configured by placing directives in plain text configuration files. The main configuration file is *usually* called `httpd.conf`. The location of this file is set at compile-time and some distributions may elect to use a different name.  Also the configuration file name may be overridden at start up with the `-f` command line flag.

The configuration file is parsed from top to bottom in sequence, and usually the order of directives matters.

In addition, **other configuration files** may be added using the [`Include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) and [`IncludeOptional`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional) directives in the `http.conf`, and wildcards `*` can be used to include many configuration files. Include files themselves may also contain the `Include` directive.

Included files will be merged with the main httpd.conf at the locations of the Include directives.

Any directive may be placed in any of these configuration files. Changes to the main configuration files are only recognized by httpd when it is started or restarted.

A fairly typical httpd.conf looks something akin to this:

```
# httpd.conf
Directives
...

IncludeOptional early-includes/*.conf

More Directives
...

IncludeOptional late-includes/*.conf

Even More Directives

IncludeOptional active-virtualhosts/*.conf
```

where any/all `*.conf` files are included in lexicological order.

I *think* your `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` is not a httpd.conf file nor an `Include` , *usually* such `/etc/sysconfig/` files are sourced by a start-up script and used set commandline parameters and options.

Comment: Very clear and, yep, your last supposition is right: that `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` looks like an options file. But where are `APACHE_MODULES` and other options documented? It seems I can't find them even with a search engine.

Comment: My RHEL/CentOS httpd.conf configures modules by loading them from an early include such as  `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf: LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so` and configures the loaded module from a late include such as `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf`

Comment: @HBruijin , I have used make to build httpd and placed it in /etc/httpd on RHEL 7.6. I am trying to resolve an issue with siteminder agent and the resolution https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=786989 asks me to update /etc/sysconfig/httpd file. Where do I find this config file. It seems like the file gets created. when I do yum install for httpd